# Parse data to mappable nested list | React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, sorting

I'm building a database where you can add comments to meetings and replies to those meetings. I took inspiration from [this article](https://phpro.org/tutorials/Creating-Threaded-Comments-With-PHP-And-Postgresql-Recursive-Query.html) since I've never done anything like this before.

I'm fetching my comments from my database and the structure looks like this:

```
"comments": [
        {
          "id": 5,
          "content": "First comment",
          "path": [
            5
          ],
          "depth": 1
        },
        {
          "id": 6,
          "content": "First reply on first comment",
          "path": [
            5,
            6
          ],
          "depth": 2
        },
        {
          "id": 7,
          "content": "Second comment",
          "path": [
            7
          ],
          "depth": 1
        },
        {
          "id": 8,
          "content": "First reply on second comment",
          "path": [
            7,
            8
          ],
          "depth": 2
        },
        {
          "id": 9,
          "content": "Second reply on second comment",
          "path": [
            7,
            9
          ],
          "depth": 2
        },
        {
          "id": 10,
          "content": "First reply on second comment second reply",
          "path": [
            7,
            9,
            10
          ],
          "depth": 3
        }
      ]
```

Currently, I'm trying to create a nested list with my React application and display the comments in a similar way as StackOverflow does. I have an idea of how the structure will look like, but I'm not too sure how to implement it.

```
comments: [
    {
        id: 5,
        content: "First comment",
        replies: [
            {
                id: 6,
                content: "First reply on first comment",
                depth: 2                               
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 100,
        content: "Comment with no replies",
        replies: []
    }

]
```

Any help on how to get started on this is greatly appreciated and I hope I've described my problem clearly.

Thanks for reading and have a nice day.

Comment: I've implemented something like this before, but I chose to convert the data into a map/object that's keyed by the ID, initially. I'd add a "root" that doesn't get rendered, and convert that object into a flat array, more similar to how you're first one looks. Then, using the depth prop, I'd set the margin so it's indented a set amount under its parent. For me, that was just another ID, but it could also just be the path you have there. Then it was a just depth-first tree rendering algo.

Comment: Thanks for comment @jktravis. I've never heard of depth-first algorithms so I'm not too sure how to implement it in my case. Maybe it's super simple, but the fact that I haven't used it before makes it taunting. Would you mind helping me a bit with it?

Comment: It certainly does sound complicated, but it's really just a recursive algorithm for searching or traversing a tree. That's really what you're working with. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search. Here, though, you're basically converting the data into react components. If you can, I'd add a `parentId` and a `children` prop to each.

Comment: Would it be too much to ask for an example? I tried my hardest yesterday, but I couldn't get it to work..

Comment: Did you happen to get this working? @MartinNordström

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is to add `parentId`, `children`, and `order` to each item. This will let you traverse the tree up or down regardless of which node you start with and to ensure the correct ordering. The `parentId` is self-explanatory, while the `children` should probably be named `childrenIds` as it just holds the IDs of the children in the appropriate order.

Then, I usually like to convert the array to a map that is keyed by some unique value like an ID. This give you an O(1) operation to get to any node that may be edited or removed. I like to use Ramda for things like this, but you could use any other utility or write your own.

#### utils.js

```
/**
 * Convert an array to an object, using the `id` as the key.
 */
 const keyById = R.indexBy(R.prop("id"));
```

Now, you need to find the comments that are on the top of the list or just under what would be "root" if you had one. Since I've chosen to use `parentId: null` for to indicate this, we can find those top-level items with this.

```
const getTopLevelParents = R.filter(x => !x.parentId);
```

With this, we can easily get our top-level items to begin iteration. This is where it might get a little more complicated. I'm also using Ramda here, so I hope it's not too unusual for understanding. The gist is, starting with the first item in the topLevel items, we recursively find the children items, sort by "order", set the depth, and concatenate that array of items to a single array. So the result is something more linear and ordered correctly. Because when we go to map this data to components, we don't want to have to skip around in order to find the parents and children. We want to be able to go from top to bottom, having already figured out all of this.

```
/**
 * Converts the mapping to an array and reorders the children so they are directly adjacent with the depth set.
 * @param treeMap Key value pair where the key is the ID and the value is the chapter
 */
function getTreeMapAsList(treeMap) {
  const topLevel = R.compose(
    getTopLevelParents,
    R.values
  )(treeMap);

  /**
   * Nest this function so it can have access to treeMap.
   */
  function getTree(data, depth = 0) {
    return R.reduce(
      (result, curr) => {
        result.push(curr);
        // hasLength is a utility that just checks if the length of an     
        // item is greater than 0 in a way that won't blow up if something
        // doesn't exist.  
        if (hasLength(R.prop("children", curr))) {
          const children = R.compose(
            R.sortBy(R.prop("order")),
            R.reduce((result, id) => {
              const child = R.prop(id, treeMap);
              if (child) {
                return R.compose(
                  R.append(R.__, result),
                  R.assoc("depth", depth + 1)
                )(child);
              }
              return result;
            }, [])
          )(curr.children);

          return result.concat(getTree(children, depth + 1));
        }
        return result;
      },
      [],
      data
    );
  }
```

The tree is now properly ordered, with appropriate depths, and has been flattened into an array. Lastly, you can map over this array with your comment component.

#### Comment.js

```
function Comment({ data }) {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        //It's important to default to zero here. You could also
        // just do this in the data or the mapper originally.
        marginLeft: `${R.propOr(0, "depth", data)}rem`
      }}
    >
      {data.content}
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### App.js

```
function App() {
  // This is the map and should be stored in state somewhere.
  // If it's changing a lot, you should memoize it.
  const treeMap = keyById(data.comments);

  // This is the array, that is now ordered with appropriate depths
  // This should also be memoized.
  const treeList = getTreeMapAsList(treeMap);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {/* Now we just have an array to iterate over. */}
        {treeList.map(item => {
          return <Comment data={item} key={item.id} />;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Here's a working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-glitter-xwlbv). Good luck!